# Step down transformer when wattage is close

Tags: transformer, step-down

Please tell me if my cooking appliance (programmable pressure cooker/slow cooker) is safe to use with my step-down transformer.  I live the UK and received a Japanese cooking appliance.

I have a step down transformer (UK 240 V to 100 V for Japanese appliances).

The step-down transformer is marked: Output 100 V. TOTAL 660 VA. MAX: 6.6 A. I understand VA is wattage and you get it by multiplying V times A.

The appliance is marked: 100 V. 700 W. [Japanese] 3.15 A. I'm reliably told the Japanese part translates as "current fuse".

The applicable wattage 700 W is higher than the transformer 660 W but not by much. The current 3.15 A is less than half 6.6 A.

I don't understand why the wattage of the applicance 700 W is greater than 100 V times 3.15 A.

Comment: 3.15 A is indeed very stange unless it’s 700 W for a very short while, but most safety agencies would not allow it. But most probably as you said, 700 W > 660 W. It will most likely overheat after 15+ minutes.

Comment: As @winny says, the problem is heat so it won't fail instantly. Might be worth powering up with the transformer plugged into one of those cheap AC power meters. If it actually draws < 660W you're good to go.

Comment: Usually, people don't bring heating and cooking appliances overseas, because the transformers are unnecessarily expensive

Answer (score 2):

The transformer rating is 660VA. That means, that it can supply a load of 660VA continuously all the time.

Your appliance is fused with 3.15A fuse, which in practice means that continuous current is even less than that, let's say approx. 2.8A. That would be near 280VA continuous.In short bursts the load is increased to 700VA, but never more than 280VA over a period of time (mean value).

So your transformer is now over sized, you could be using 300VA.

As an example from one of my applications:

- The heat sealing wire has approx 10kW power and it is supplied by a transformer of 2.4kVA. It works for 2s and it cools for 3min. Duty cycle approx. 1%

You can overload the transformer for various times, if you need just a small burst. The only limitation is, that the secondary voltage sags if you expect too much. Therefore a transformer of 100VA (1% of 10kVA) is not suitable, so there is still a large transformer which is completely cool as it does nothing most of the time.

EDIT:

Beside using smaller transformer, you could use an auto transformer 240/100 400VA it would have a weight of approx 1.7kg.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand VA is wattage and you get it by multiplying V times A.

You are correct that VA is found by multiplying V times A. In some cases, that is the same as wattage, but not always. Some things take power from the mains line, and then return that power. That is counted in a VA rating. However, the returned power (it is called reactive power in electrical jargon) does not contribute to a wattage rating. VA is always greater than or equal to wattage.

> The applicable wattage 700 W is higher than the transformer 660 W but not by much.

Putting aside the wattage vs VA rating for a bit, I would never advise someone to use a transformer above its rated VA, even 10%. You run a risk if you do so. If you are lucky, you will blow a fuse, or pop a circuit breaker. If you are unlucky, you will destroy the transformer. If you are really unlucky, your transformer will be on something flammable, and it will start a fire.

> I don't understand why the wattage of the appliance 700 W is greater than 100 V times 3.15 A.

I do not understand either. If you are lucky, the appliance is not 700W and you can use it with your transformer. However, I can't think of a reasonable scenario where an appliance would be rated simultaneously 100V, 3.15A and 700W.

Comment: Thanks all. I have a hideous 1600 W step down transformer in storage that I have trouble lifting, but I'll use it as at least it's going to be safe.

Comment: I'm betting that if it's an induction-cooker, it has a horrible power factor of 0.45 and 315W *real* watts are consumed, while 700W is the VA (*real and reactive*) watts rating - what is really drawn (and recirculated) to the plug.